# Configuring signalR to work in IIS6

Tags: iis, asp.net-ajax, signalr

I'm working on a signalR project, and was running into HTTP 404 errors when deploying to a server running IIS6 (Windows Server 2003). The 404 was on the signalr/hubs reference. It was suggested in the JabbR chat room to add a wildcard map (* to aspnet_isapi) in IIS to resolve the issue. That did in fact resolve the 404 issue, but I began receiving the error "ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load".

If I take the wildcard off, the AJAX loads and functions as expected. I have to believe that this mapping is not the correct way to go; perhaps there is a handler that needs registered in the web.config file.

It's worth noting that the entire solution works perfectly on my local (Windows 7) development machine.

Comment: It is worth clarifying that if I take the IIS Wildcard off, I actually get a javascript error "Unable to set value of the property 'addMessage': object is null or undefined".